# Angular4 http get parse error

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http, typescript

Request `mydomain/request` returns json string like `"accepted"` or `"declined"`

I would use request in angular to get this string :

```
  getStatus(jobOfferId): Promise<string> {
    const url = "someurl";

    return this.httpClientService.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response as string);
  }
```

This would work in angular 2, but I've just upgraded to angular 4 and this request returns an error instead

`"Http failure during parsing for https://mydomain/request"`

Comment: can you include a sample of the response?

Comment: @ochi I did, it's just a single string wrapped in brackets `"`

Comment: This cannot work in Angular 2 because Angular 2 doesn't have `HttpClient`.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović what do you mean?

Comment: [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http) has been added in version 4. Is that the `httpClientService` in your code? You state that you're migrating from version 2 to version 4, but this is impossible because `HttpClient` did not exist in 2.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Nowhere in my code I mentioned using HttpClient class specifically. httpClientService is an abstract injection that handles http related stuff. The class itsself was migrated.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović currently httpClientService.get is the same as HttpClient.get but before migration it had different implementation

Comment: @Benedictus are you looking for something like [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)

Comment: sure you mentioned what the response was but is the response of the form: `{"accepted"}` or `"accepted"` or something else? - either way, it seems odd to fail it but in the process of reproducing the issue, it's better to be sure

Comment: Like i wrote `"accepted"`

Answer (score 3):

JSON is the default expected response type. You can try forcing using "text" instead and print the result just to understand what is happening:

```
httpClient.get('http://some.com/endpoint/', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: ``error TS2345: Argument of type '{ responseType: "text"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.``

Also, ``headers`` is not defined.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig I removed the optional header from the example however the responseType: ''text' is correct. You can check a similar example [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-new-angular-httpclient-api-9e5c85fe3361). Also this answer was for Angular 4, Angular 5 is having [a new http service](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-5-making-api-calls-httpclient-service)

Comment: Confirming that this is the correct approach if your response type is plain text instead of JSON.  You mention in a comment above that your httpClientService is an abstraction layer over angular's httpClient.  If this is not working, the issue is likely in how you implement your abstraction.